# Regex test for "number.number.number"

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to test a string to make sure it's a number.number.number.

Example would be `10.8.1`

I found this regex `/^\d+$/` tests for a number, but how can I add the dots condition?

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?

Comment: @MikeCole I'd really like to know!

Comment: I think it would be as simple as [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+

Comment: @MikeCole Presumably because "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @Michelle "I found this regex /^\d+$/ tests for a number" ???

Comment: please at least try http://regexpal.com/ before posting something so easily regex'd. Also http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: @MikeCole A quick glance at any regex documentation or tutorial would have answered this, in other words "no research effort"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel RegEx can be tricky. That same principle could be applied to a lot of questions asked on this site. Anyway, no point in continuing this conversation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I did research, but Regex is very confusing when you barely use it. The accepted answer was extremely helpful and allowed me to actually understand the difference between the Regex I included in my question and the desired result.

Comment: I like using (http://txt2re.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd probably want to create a regex as follows:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

The `^` means "start of phrase", the `$` means "end of phrase", `\d+` says "digit one or more times in a row", and `\.` means "." but must be escaped with the leading `\` due to `.` having a special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool b = Regex.Match("10.8.1", @"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$").Success;
```

If you want to limit the number of digits:

```
bool b = Regex.Match("10.8.1", @"^\d{1,2}\.\d{1}\.\d{1}$").Success;
```