# How to validate a string entry to ensure it is in a format of 'Number.Number.Number' (1.2.3)

Tags: c#, string, validation

I have a system where i create releases and i must give the release version via a textbox. The field it is stored in in my database is an nvarchar so a string.

I want to make sure this entry is formatted so it is always a number then a full stop then a number then a full stop and then a number again (1.2.3). Can anyone help me with making sure this is the case on the button click to submit?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For this a regular expression like \d\.\d\.\d would be a possible solution.

Comment: `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2}$` pattern (regular expressions)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683744/regex-test-for-number-number-number

Comment: there are many ways that you can check regex, String.Format function etc.. what have you actually tried on your own..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using RegEx you can validate your Input. I assume by number you mean one digit:

```
string text = "1.2.3";
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(text, "^\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d$");
```

If you want to validate one or more digits you have to add `+`

```
string text = "12.23.34";
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(text, "^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex :

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

The ^ means Start, the $ means end,
 \d+ says "more than one digit is available in the row", and . means "." but must be escaped with the leading \ due to . having a special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Longer way, without using regex (I have an hate for regex... just a matter of taste, I know I should learn them and use them when appropriate...)

```
bool IsInputValid(string input)
{
    string[] values = input.Split('.');
    if (values.Length != 3)
        return false;
    int tmp = 0;
    foreach (string s in values)
        if (!int.TryParse(s, out tmp))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```